# Demographics information of google analytics on GeneXus

Tags: google-analytics, genexus

I have configured google analytics in my app, but I want to enable it to get the demographics information. According to google, I have to make changes in my code to enable it. I need to put the following code:

```
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

How can I do this in GeneXus?

Answer (score 0):

To enable Advertising Reporting Features in your app, the Google Analytics SDK v4 is required, and that version is supported as from GeneXus Salto ( X Evolution 3 supports v2).